# Is there any hope with this integral?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, exponential-function

I can't figure out how to take this integral. Looks pretty standard to me, but somehow can't find anything helpful in the literature:

$\int_0^{2\pi} d\phi\; (1-2 a \cos \phi + a^2)^{k+ (\kappa/2)} e^{-i( \ell - \kappa) \phi} $

MMA is stuck with it as well, which makes me suspicious if the closed form exists...

Any help with this is highly appreciated!

Comment: One can write $1-2a \cos\phi+a^2=(a-e^{i \phi})(a-e^{-i \phi})=|a-e^{i \phi}|^2$ ; I would then try integration by residues.

Comment: @Jean Marie Thank you for the idea! I'll try it out.